# Error while installing MPICH: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: executable, mpi

I am trying to install mpich 3.2.1 on ubuntu 16. When i execute

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/mpich 2>&1 | tee c.tx
```

i get:

```
checking for icc... no
checking for pgcc... no
checking for xlc... no
checking for xlC... no
checking for pathcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/aoguz/Downloads/mpich-3.2.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Help me out please.

config.log file:

```
    This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by MPICH configure 3.2.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/opt/mpich

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = aoguz-Inspiron-N5110
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.15.0-38-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 20:16:04 UTC 2018

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/aoguz/bin
PATH: /home/aoguz/.local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:5211: checking for icc
configure:5241: result: no
configure:5211: checking for pgcc
configure:5241: result: no
configure:5211: checking for xlc
configure:5241: result: no
configure:5211: checking for xlC
configure:5241: result: no
configure:5211: checking for pathcc
configure:5241: result: no
configure:5211: checking for gcc
configure:5227: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:5238: result: gcc
configure:5269: checking for C compiler version
configure:5278: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:5289: $? = 0
configure:5278: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 
configure:5289: $? = 0
configure:5278: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:5289: $? = 1
configure:5278: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:5289: $? = 1
configure:5309: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:5331: gcc      conftest.c  >&5
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.
configure:5335: $? = 1
configure:5373: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "MPICH"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "mpich"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.2.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "MPICH 3.2.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "discuss@mpich.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.mpich.org/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:5378: error: in `/home/aoguz/Downloads/mpich-3.2.1':
configure:5380: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_AR_FLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_FLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_F77_set=
ac_cv_env_F77_value=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_FC_set=
ac_cv_env_FC_value=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GCOV_set=
ac_cv_env_GCOV_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_MPICHLIB_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_MPICHLIB_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_MPICHLIB_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_MPICHLIB_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_MPICHLIB_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_MPICHLIB_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_MPICHLIB_FCFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_MPICHLIB_FCFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_MPICHLIB_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_MPICHLIB_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_MPICXXLIBNAME_set=
ac_cv_env_MPICXXLIBNAME_value=
ac_cv_env_MPIFCLIBNAME_set=
ac_cv_env_MPIFCLIBNAME_value=
ac_cv_env_MPILIBNAME_set=
ac_cv_env_MPILIBNAME_value=
ac_cv_env_MPLLIBNAME_set=
ac_cv_env_MPLLIBNAME_value=
ac_cv_env_OPALIBNAME_set=
ac_cv_env_OPALIBNAME_value=
ac_cv_env_PAMILIBNAME_set=
ac_cv_env_PAMILIBNAME_value=
ac_cv_env_PMPILIBNAME_set=
ac_cv_env_PMPILIBNAME_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
pac_cv_my_conf_dir=/home/aoguz/Downloads/mpich-3.2.1

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ABIVERSION='13:1:1'
ABIVERSIONFLAGS='-version-info $(ABIVERSION)'
ACLOCAL=''
ADDRESS_KIND=''
ALLOCA=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR=''
AM_BACKSLASH=''
AM_DEFAULT_V=''
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY=''
AM_V=''
AR=''
AR_FLAGS=''
AS=''
ASSERT_LEVEL=''
AUTOCONF=''
AUTOHEADER=''
AUTOMAKE=''
AWK=''
BASH_SHELL=''
BGQ_INSTALL_DIR=''
BSEND_OVERHEAD=''
BUILD_BASH_SCRIPTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_BASH_SCRIPTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_CH3_FALSE=''
BUILD_CH3_NEMESIS_FALSE=''
BUILD_CH3_NEMESIS_TRUE=''
BUILD_CH3_SOCK_FALSE=''
BUILD_CH3_SOCK_TRUE=''
BUILD_CH3_TRUE=''
BUILD_CH3_UTIL_FTB_FALSE=''
BUILD_CH3_UTIL_FTB_TRUE=''
BUILD_CH3_UTIL_SOCK_FALSE=''
BUILD_CH3_UTIL_SOCK_TRUE=''
BUILD_COVERAGE_FALSE=''
BUILD_COVERAGE_TRUE=''
BUILD_CXX_BINDING_FALSE=''
BUILD_CXX_BINDING_TRUE=''
BUILD_DEBUGGER_DLL_FALSE=''
BUILD_DEBUGGER_DLL_TRUE=''
BUILD_F08_BINDING_FALSE=''
BUILD_F08_BINDING_TRUE=''
BUILD_F77_BINDING_FALSE=''
BUILD_F77_BINDING_TRUE=''
BUILD_FC_BINDING_FALSE=''
BUILD_FC_BINDING_TRUE=''
BUILD_HCOLL_FALSE=''
BUILD_HCOLL_TRUE=''
BUILD_LOGGING_RLOG_FALSE=''
BUILD_LOGGING_RLOG_TRUE=''
BUILD_MPID_COMMON_DATATYPE_FALSE=''
BUILD_MPID_COMMON_DATATYPE_TRUE=''
BUILD_MPID_COMMON_SCHED_FALSE=''
BUILD_MPID_COMMON_SCHED_TRUE=''
BUILD_MPID_COMMON_SOCK_FALSE=''
BUILD_MPID_COMMON_SOCK_POLL_FALSE=''
BUILD_MPID_COMMON_SOCK_POLL_TRUE=''
BUILD_MPID_COMMON_SOCK_TRUE=''
BUILD_MPID_COMMON_THREAD_FALSE=''
BUILD_MPID_COMMON_THREAD_TRUE=''
BUILD_NAMEPUB_FILE_FALSE=''
BUILD_NAMEPUB_FILE_TRUE=''
BUILD_NAMEPUB_PMI_FALSE=''
BUILD_NAMEPUB_PMI_TRUE=''
BUILD_NEMESIS_NETMOD_LLC_FALSE=''
BUILD_NEMESIS_NETMOD_LLC_TRUE=''
BUILD_NEMESIS_NETMOD_MXM_FALSE=''
BUILD_NEMESIS_NETMOD_MXM_TRUE=''
BUILD_NEMESIS_NETMOD_OFI_FALSE=''
BUILD_NEMESIS_NETMOD_OFI_TRUE=''
BUILD_NEMESIS_NETMOD_PORTALS4_FALSE=''
BUILD_NEMESIS_NETMOD_PORTALS4_TRUE=''
BUILD_NEMESIS_NETMOD_TCP_FALSE=''
BUILD_NEMESIS_NETMOD_TCP_TRUE=''
BUILD_PAMID_FALSE=''
BUILD_PAMID_TRUE=''
BUILD_PMI_PMI2_FALSE=''
BUILD_PMI_PMI2_POE_FALSE=''
BUILD_PMI_PMI2_POE_TRUE=''
BUILD_PMI_PMI2_SIMPLE_FALSE=''
BUILD_PMI_PMI2_SIMPLE_TRUE=''
BUILD_PMI_PMI2_TRUE=''
BUILD_PMI_SIMPLE_FALSE=''
BUILD_PMI_SIMPLE_TRUE=''
BUILD_PMI_SLURM_FALSE=''
BUILD_PMI_SLURM_TRUE=''
BUILD_PM_GFORKER_FALSE=''
BUILD_PM_GFORKER_TRUE=''
BUILD_PM_HYDRA_FALSE=''
BUILD_PM_HYDRA_TRUE=''
BUILD_PM_REMSHELL_FALSE=''
BUILD_PM_REMSHELL_TRUE=''
BUILD_PM_UTIL_FALSE=''
BUILD_PM_UTIL_TRUE=''
BUILD_PROFILING_LIB_FALSE=''
BUILD_PROFILING_LIB_TRUE=''
BUILD_ROMIO_FALSE=''
BUILD_ROMIO_TRUE=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=' '
CMB_1INT_ALIGNMENT=''
CMB_STATUS_ALIGNMENT=''
CONFIGURE_ARGS_CLEAN='--prefix=/opt/mpich'
CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS=' '\''--prefix=/opt/mpich'\'''
COUNT_KIND=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=' '
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=' '
CYGPATH_W=''
C_LINKPATH_SHL=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DEVICE=''
DISABLE_TAG_SUPPORT=''
DLLIMPORT=''
DLLTOOL=''
DOCTEXT=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
F08_2INT=''
F08_AINT=''
F08_BYTE=''
F08_CHAR=''
F08_COMPLEX16=''
F08_COMPLEX32=''
F08_COMPLEX8=''
F08_COUNT=''
F08_CXX_BOOL=''
F08_CXX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
F08_CXX_FLOAT_COMPLEX=''
F08_CXX_LONG_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
F08_C_AINT=''
F08_C_BOOL=''
F08_C_COMPLEX=''
F08_C_COUNT=''
F08_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
F08_C_FLOAT_COMPLEX=''
F08_C_LONG_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
F08_C_OFFSET=''
F08_DOUBLE=''
F08_DOUBLE_INT=''
F08_FLOAT=''
F08_FLOAT_INT=''
F08_INT16_T=''
F08_INT32_T=''
F08_INT64_T=''
F08_INT8_T=''
F08_INT=''
F08_INTEGER16=''
F08_INTEGER1=''
F08_INTEGER2=''
F08_INTEGER4=''
F08_INTEGER8=''
F08_LB=''
F08_LONG=''
F08_LONG_DOUBLE=''
F08_LONG_DOUBLE_INT=''
F08_LONG_INT=''
F08_LONG_LONG=''
F08_LONG_LONG_INT=''
F08_OFFSET=''
F08_PACKED=''
F08_REAL16=''
F08_REAL4=''
F08_REAL8=''
F08_SHORT=''
F08_SHORT_INT=''
F08_SIGNED_CHAR=''
F08_UB=''
F08_UINT16_T=''
F08_UINT32_T=''
F08_UINT64_T=''
F08_UINT8_T=''
F08_UNSIGNED=''
F08_UNSIGNED_CHAR=''
F08_UNSIGNED_INT=''
F08_UNSIGNED_LONG=''
F08_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG=''
F08_UNSIGNED_SHORT=''
F08_WCHAR=''
F77=''
F77CPP=''
F77_COMPLEX16=''
F77_COMPLEX32=''
F77_COMPLEX8=''
F77_INCDIR=''
F77_INTEGER16=''
F77_INTEGER1=''
F77_INTEGER2=''
F77_INTEGER4=''
F77_INTEGER8=''
F77_LIBDIR_LEADER=''
F77_NAME_MANGLE=''
F77_OTHER_LIBS=''
F77_REAL16=''
F77_REAL4=''
F77_REAL8=''
FC=''
FCCPP=''
FCEXT=''
FCFLAGS=' '
FCINC=''
FCINCFLAG=''
FCMODEXT=''
FCMODINCFLAG=''
FCMODINCSPEC=''
FCMODOUTFLAG=''
FC_ALL_INTEGER_MODELS=''
FC_DOUBLE_MODEL=''
FC_INTEGER_MODEL=''
FC_INTEGER_MODEL_MAP=''
FC_OTHER_LIBS=''
FC_REAL_MODEL=''
FC_WORK_FILES_ARG=''
FFLAGS=' '
FGREP=''
FILE=''
FLIBS=''
FORTRAN_BINDING=''
FORTRAN_MPI_OFFSET=''
GCOV=''
GNUCXX_MINORVERSION=''
GNUCXX_VERSION=''
GREP=''
HAVE_CXX_EXCEPTIONS=''
HAVE_ERROR_CHECKING=''
HAVE_ROMIO=''
INCLUDE_MPICXX_H=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_MPIF77_FALSE=''
INSTALL_MPIF77_TRUE=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM=''
INTEGER_KIND=''
INTERLIB_DEPS=''
KILLALL=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LPMPILIBNAME=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKE=''
MAKEINFO=''
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P=''
MPIBASEMODNAME=''
MPICC_NAME=''
MPICHLIB_CFLAGS=''
MPICHLIB_CPPFLAGS=''
MPICHLIB_CXXFLAGS=''
MPICHLIB_FCFLAGS=''
MPICHLIB_FFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPICC_CFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPICC_CPPFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPICC_LDFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPICC_LIBS=''
MPICH_MPICXX_CPPFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPICXX_CXXFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPICXX_LDFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPICXX_LIBS=''
MPICH_MPIF77_CPPFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPIF77_FFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPIF77_LDFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPIF77_LIBS=''
MPICH_MPIFORT_CPPFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPIFORT_FCFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPIFORT_LDFLAGS=''
MPICH_MPIFORT_LIBS=''
MPICH_NUMVERSION='30201300'
MPICH_RELEASE_DATE='Fri Nov 10 20:21:01 CST 2017'
MPICH_TIMER_KIND=''
MPICH_TIMER_TYPE=''
MPICH_VERSION='3.2.1'
MPICONSTMODNAME=''
MPICPP_NAME=''
MPICXXLIBNAME=''
MPICXX_NAME=''
MPIF77_NAME=''
MPIF90_NAME=''
MPIFCLIBNAME=''
MPIFORT_NAME=''
MPIFPMPI=''
MPILIBNAME=''
MPIMODNAME=''
MPIR_CXX_BOOL=''
MPIR_CXX_COMPLEX=''
MPIR_CXX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
MPIR_CXX_LONG_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
MPISIZEOFMODNAME=''
MPIU_DLL_SPEC_DEF=''
MPIU_PINT=''
MPI_2COMPLEX=''
MPI_2DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION=''
MPI_2INT=''
MPI_2INTEGER=''
MPI_2REAL=''
MPI_AINT=''
MPI_AINT_DATATYPE=''
MPI_AINT_FMT_DEC_SPEC=''
MPI_AINT_FMT_HEX_SPEC=''
MPI_BYTE=''
MPI_CHAR=''
MPI_CHARACTER=''
MPI_COMPLEX16=''
MPI_COMPLEX32=''
MPI_COMPLEX8=''
MPI_COMPLEX=''
MPI_COUNT=''
MPI_COUNT_DATATYPE=''
MPI_C_BOOL=''
MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
MPI_C_FLOAT_COMPLEX=''
MPI_C_INTERFACE_CDESC_NAME=''
MPI_C_INTERFACE_GLUE_NAME=''
MPI_C_INTERFACE_NAME=''
MPI_C_INTERFACE_NOBUF_NAME=''
MPI_C_INTERFACE_TYPES_NAME=''
MPI_C_LONG_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
MPI_DOUBLE=''
MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
MPI_DOUBLE_INT=''
MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION=''
MPI_F08_CALLBACKS_NAME=''
MPI_F08_COMPILE_CONSTANTS_NAME=''
MPI_F08_LINK_CONSTANTS_NAME=''
MPI_F08_NAME=''
MPI_F08_TYPES_NAME=''
MPI_F77_2INT=''
MPI_F77_AINT=''
MPI_F77_BYTE=''
MPI_F77_CHAR=''
MPI_F77_COUNT=''
MPI_F77_CXX_BOOL=''
MPI_F77_CXX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
MPI_F77_CXX_FLOAT_COMPLEX=''
MPI_F77_CXX_LONG_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
MPI_F77_C_BOOL=''
MPI_F77_C_COMPLEX=''
MPI_F77_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
MPI_F77_C_FLOAT_COMPLEX=''
MPI_F77_C_LONG_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
MPI_F77_DOUBLE=''
MPI_F77_DOUBLE_INT=''
MPI_F77_FLOAT=''
MPI_F77_FLOAT_INT=''
MPI_F77_INT16_T=''
MPI_F77_INT32_T=''
MPI_F77_INT64_T=''
MPI_F77_INT8_T=''
MPI_F77_INT=''
MPI_F77_LB=''
MPI_F77_LONG=''
MPI_F77_LONG_DOUBLE=''
MPI_F77_LONG_DOUBLE_INT=''
MPI_F77_LONG_INT=''
MPI_F77_LONG_LONG=''
MPI_F77_LONG_LONG_INT=''
MPI_F77_OFFSET=''
MPI_F77_PACKED=''
MPI_F77_SHORT=''
MPI_F77_SHORT_INT=''
MPI_F77_SIGNED_CHAR=''
MPI_F77_UB=''
MPI_F77_UINT16_T=''
MPI_F77_UINT32_T=''
MPI_F77_UINT64_T=''
MPI_F77_UINT8_T=''
MPI_F77_UNSIGNED=''
MPI_F77_UNSIGNED_CHAR=''
MPI_F77_UNSIGNED_LONG=''
MPI_F77_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG=''
MPI_F77_UNSIGNED_SHORT=''
MPI_F77_WCHAR=''
MPI_FINT=''
MPI_FLOAT=''
MPI_FLOAT_INT=''
MPI_INT16_T=''
MPI_INT32_T=''
MPI_INT64_T=''
MPI_INT8_T=''
MPI_INT=''
MPI_INTEGER16=''
MPI_INTEGER1=''
MPI_INTEGER2=''
MPI_INTEGER4=''
MPI_INTEGER8=''
MPI_INTEGER=''
MPI_LB=''
MPI_LOGICAL=''
MPI_LONG=''
MPI_LONG_DOUBLE=''
MPI_LONG_DOUBLE_INT=''
MPI_LONG_INT=''
MPI_LONG_LONG=''
MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING=''
MPI_MAX_LIBRARY_VERSION_STRING=''
MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME=''
MPI_OFFSET=''
MPI_OFFSET_DATATYPE=''
MPI_OFFSET_TYPEDEF=''
MPI_PACKED=''
MPI_REAL16=''
MPI_REAL4=''
MPI_REAL8=''
MPI_REAL=''
MPI_SHORT=''
MPI_SHORT_INT=''
MPI_SIGNED_CHAR=''
MPI_STATUS_SIZE=''
MPI_UB=''
MPI_UINT16_T=''
MPI_UINT32_T=''
MPI_UINT64_T=''
MPI_UINT8_T=''
MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR=''
MPI_UNSIGNED_INT=''
MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG=''
MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG=''
MPI_UNSIGNED_SHORT=''
MPI_WCHAR=''
MPLLIBNAME=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OFFSET_KIND=''
OPALIBNAME=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='discuss@mpich.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='MPICH'
PACKAGE_STRING='MPICH 3.2.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='mpich'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.mpich.org/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.2.1'
PAMILIBNAME=''
PAPI_INCLUDE=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL=''
PMPILIBNAME=''
PMPI_F08_NAME=''
PRIMARY_PM_GFORKER_FALSE=''
PRIMARY_PM_GFORKER_TRUE=''
PRIMARY_PM_REMSHELL_FALSE=''
PRIMARY_PM_REMSHELL_TRUE=''
QUEUE_BINARY_SEARCH_SUPPORT_FALSE=''
QUEUE_BINARY_SEARCH_SUPPORT_TRUE=''
RANLIB=''
REQD=''
REQI1=''
REQI2=''
REQI8=''
RSH=''
SED=''
SET_CFLAGS=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SHLIB_EXT=''
SIZEOF_FC_CHARACTER=''
SIZEOF_FC_DOUBLE_PRECISION=''
SIZEOF_FC_INTEGER=''
SIZEOF_FC_REAL=''
SIZEOF_MPI_STATUS=''
SSH=''
STRIP=''
USER_CFLAGS=''
USER_CPPFLAGS=''
USER_CXXFLAGS=''
USER_EXTRA_LIBS=''
USER_FCFLAGS=''
USER_FFLAGS=''
USER_LDFLAGS=''
USER_LIBS=''
USE_DBG_LOGGING=''
VERSION=''
VPATH=''
WRAPPER_CFLAGS=''
WRAPPER_CPPFLAGS=''
WRAPPER_CXXFLAGS=''
WRAPPER_EXTRA_LIBS=''
WRAPPER_FCFLAGS=''
WRAPPER_FFLAGS=''
WRAPPER_LDFLAGS=''
WRAPPER_LIBS=''
WRAPPER_RPATH_LDFLAGS=''
WTIME_DOUBLE_TYPE=''
XARGS_NODATA_OPT=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ac_ct_F77=''
ac_ct_FC=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot=''
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar=''
am__untar=''
bindings=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
channel_name=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
device_name=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
enable_wrapper_rpath='yes'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
libmpi_so_version='13:1:1'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
master_top_builddir=''
master_top_srcdir=''
mkdir_p=''
mmx_copy_s=''
modincdir=''
mpich_libtool_static_flag=''
mpllib=''
mpllibdir=''
mplsrcdir=''
nemesis_nets_array=''
nemesis_nets_array_sz=''
nemesis_nets_dirs=''
nemesis_nets_func_array=''
nemesis_nets_func_decl=''
nemesis_nets_macro_defs=''
nemesis_nets_strings=''
nemesis_networks=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
opalib=''
opalibdir=''
opasrcdir=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pkgconfigdir=''
pm_name=''
prefix='/opt/mpich'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
subdirs=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

cc_shlib_conf=''
cxx_shlib_conf=''
f77_shlib_conf=''
fc_shlib_conf=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "MPICH"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "mpich"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.2.1"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "MPICH 3.2.1"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "discuss@mpich.org"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.mpich.org/"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Do you have binutils installed?

Comment: Yeah, btw i've installed a fresh ubuntu 16 and have no problem now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try `apt install build-essential`, this should install the necessities for building stuff, your build should work after tht.
2. Want to make your life even easier? `apt install --install-recommends --install-suggests mpich`.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Installed a fresh ubuntu and got rid of the problem.